# App is resuming form a On-click method When I Exit and Reopen It?Android

Tags: android, android-activity, exit

I have done a 3 pages activity in that

1. SplashScreen
2. MainActivity
3. Results

So here I am passing a value to server from `MainActivity` with `URL` query string to `Results` page over there it will display results.

I am passing like this

**MainActivity :**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.maina);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar2);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        final Button click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sc);
        click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MainActivity.this.finish();
                //MainActivity.this.finishAndRemoveTask();
                Intent la = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Results.class);
                la.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                la.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                la.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                la.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                startActivity(la);
            }
        });
}
```

So it will display some value as results. Over there I have added a handler for results after `9000ms` it will again back to `MainActivity`

**Results :**

```
new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Results.this.finish();

        Intent v = new Intent(Results.this, SplashScreen.class);
        v.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        v.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        v.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        v.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        startActivity(v);
    }
}, 9000);
```

And at the part of main activity I have added an alert on back-pressed with Yes/No option for exit entire app

**MainActivity :**

```
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Do You Want to Exit App!");
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Click Yes to Exit!")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                moveTaskToBack(true);
                                MainActivity.this.finish();
                                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                                System.exit(0);
                            }
                        })

                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Here it's exiting app successfully but when I re-open the application it's starting from `Results` page even I am moving from `Results` to `SplashScreen` in handler.

Here I have removed in MainActivity

```
/* @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}*/
```

But it's always starting from `Results` page. Can anyone suggest how to exit this app completely or how to stop resume from results page?

**Update**

Here problem with exit...I am giving exit option on back pressed

So I have two scenarios

**Scenario 1**

When I launch the app it will start from `SplashScreen` --> `MainActivity`. So here I am exiting app at `MainActivity` - it's exiting fine. Here exit is working fine.

When I re-open the app after exit, it will start from `SplashScreen` --> `MainActivity`

**Scenario 2**

It starts same as first but in `MainActivity` I have a button. When I click on that button, I will pass a `URL` query string with `Intent` then it will start from the `Results` page after 9000Ms it will again go to `SplashScreen` --> `MainActivity`

So here also I am exiting app at `MainActivity`

But when I re-open the app after exit, it will start from `Results` page form and doing that handler even and again going to `SplashScreen`

Can anyone suggest what is missing I have given `MainActivity` `onCreate()` and `onBackPressed()`....

There is no `onResume()`.. But I am facing same issue with `Scenario2`.

Comment: Where are you calling the first peice of code that launches the result activity?

Comment: I am using Intent to call Results activity at `OnCreate()`

Comment: @MLN No dude, he meant in which method? Check my answer below

Comment: @MLN Yes, but where are you calling it? Please post more code.

Comment: Please Check my Updated Code every 1

Comment: Have you tried removing that `moveTaskToBack(true);` and check is it working fine

Comment: If I remove `moveTaskToBack(true);` its going to Splass Screen ... Here I want to Exit App so I have added it

Answer (score 0):

Try with change

From:

```
MainActivity.this.finish();
```

To

```
MainActivity.this.finishAndRemoveTask();
```

Comment: Thanks for Response @Experanz0 but Here I am using `API21` as Min and it must be `API21`

Comment: @MLN So You can use this. Check documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.AppTask.html . Added in API 21

Answer (score 0):

The Handler that you have created in Results class is causing memory leak.That handler is still keeping reference of activity and is running in background.Try to create a handler like this.

```
Runnable runnable;
Handler newHandler;

newHandler = new Handler();
runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            //update UI
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
};
newHandler.postDelayed(runnable,0);
```

and make sure to remove all the messages in onStop() of Activity by calling

```
newHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```

or this is a better implementation

http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
finishAndRemoveTask();
```

or
`finishAffinity();`

Answer (score 0):

Where have you written the code for opening Result activity? Is it in the onCreate() or onStart() method of the Main activity? If yes then move it to a listener of any view's click event..

Create a button in your layout xml and then write the below code in your onCreate() method:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MainActivity.this.finish();
            //MainActivity.this.finishAndRemoveTask();
            Intent la = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Results.class);
            la.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
            la.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            la.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            la.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            startActivity(la);
        }
    });
```

Comment: At `OnCreate() `

Comment: Thats the real problem.. When your activity starts, it instantly finish itself and opens the Result activity..
If you want to open a Result activity, then create a button and on that button's click listener open the Result activity..

Comment: What? I already have a Button and its opening .... Here Problem with Exit and Resume

Answer (score 0):

Add this line after startActivity in handler and check

Results.this.finish();

Comment: I have Removed this at Intent... It remains Same.. But  If i remove this at Onback pressed its not even exiting

Answer (score 0):

```
new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        Intent v = new Intent(Results.this, SplashScreen.class);
        v.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        v.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        v.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        v.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        startActivity(v);
        Results.this.finish();
    }
}, 9000);
```

finish() should call after startActivity().You used finish() is first.I think that is wrong.

Comment: thanks @H Zan I already Tried it ,.... Here The Problem is that It goes back to splash screen and then MainActivity after Results then I am Exiting MainActivity But When I open Activity Its starting form Results instead of Splash

Comment: It doesn't matter. Calling `finish()` doesn't return a method, `startActivity()` will be called for sure

Answer (score 0):

This is being caused by each Activity having it's own task. Is there a reason why you are using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`? Just remove it, as your design does not need it, and you should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for back pressed button.
This may work for you.

```
      @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.shutdown)
                    .setTitle("Warning!!!")
                    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to Logout?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            //finish();
                           // exit(0);
                           Intent intent = new 
                           Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActitivy.class);
                           intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                           intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
                           startActivity(intent);

                        }

                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .show();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks @ Sanjay Kumaar ......... Here  On back Pressed I am Exiting App Not moving to Startup screen... I am Exiting Entire App

Comment: I am adding Another Answer that may Help you-@MLN

Comment: i changed some thing in this. Try it once again

Comment: Thanks @ Sanjay Kumaar ... Here Problem with On resume or Exit,,, I am Giving Exit option on back pressed.. Here its exiting Successfully If I open it after exiting its showing from results page.. If exit without going to Results page its working fine... Your code is ok but its not exiting entire app